# How autorun supervisord in php-fpm container

Tags: docker, supervisord

I have php-fpm container with installed supervisor. But using command: `CMD ["usr/bin/supervisord"]` in Docker file made container finishing with fail(Unlinking stale socket /var/run/supervisor.sock). Run as daemon. But if remove CMD, and run command ourself in bash after container ran, its finish ok.

EDIT: I use Laravel framework, and I need to start queue listener and other processes.

Comment: If you're using the Docker Hub `php:fpm` image, you shouldn't need to do anything special: the image already knows how to run `php-fpm` as the main container process, and you don't need supervisord.  In general you shouldn't need supervisord at all.  Do you need a setup with multiple containers, maybe based on Docker Compose?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidMaze in php-fpm container exist many php scripts those should be work always. Therefore i want support their status with supervisor. Thx

Comment: If you need a daemon-like worker process (e.g. a queue listener), you might be better off to separate it into another container, where your PHP job is your entrypoint. You don't need FPM in this container. Use FPM where you handle your web traffic.

Comment: @jossif in php-fpm container work websocket-server. I just want to run supevisord in php-fpm. It's possible if run command(usr/bin/supervisord) ourself. But i cant set autorun

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue.
I set command `usr/bin/supervisord && php-fpm` and it worked correctly. Without running `php-fpm` command, the container stops at supervisord and fails.

Comment: `usr/bin/supervisord && php-fpm`

Answer (score -1):

Use webdevops images it contains supervisord without any issue

webdevops/php-nginx:7.4

add your config path in the container is

`/opt/docker/etc/supervisor.d/MY_CONF.conf`
Don't assign user when running (supervisor needs root)

Comment: especially i need to run supervisor in php-fpm(( In my supervisor conf user:root. I don't understand why the same manually run action works but when running docker automatically results in an error

Comment: add your Dockerfile please